# What are the competing formulas for determining target Residual Alkalinity from SRM?

Tags: srm

In John Palmer's spread sheet, he calculates the low target RA as

```
SRM * 12.2 - 122
```

He calculates the high target RA as

```
(SRM-5.2)*12.2.
```

This [BYO](http://byo.com/hops/item/1545-understanding-residual-alkalinity-ph-advanced-homebrewing) article states that

```
`target SRM = 0.14 * RA[CaCO3] + 5.2`,
```

or to restate it,

```
`RA as CaCO3 = (SRM - 5.2) / 0.14`
```

and taking the reciprocal of the divisor we get

```
RA as CaC03 = (SRM - 5.2) * 7.14
```

This is similar to John Palmer's high target of `(SRM-5.2)*12.2`.

So given a beer with 33 SRM, The BYO produces a target RA of ~200 and Palmer's high target produces a target RA of ~339 (his low target is 280).

How many competing formulas are there?

Which ones are used in the brewing software and how did they get selected over a competing formula?

Comment: These relationships should be largely ignored, IMO.  You can put the same ingredients in three very different water profiles and you'd get three different RA values all for the same SRM.  Couple this with the fact that if you do use SRM to calculate RA, you are using a calculated value (SRM) to calculate another value (RA)!  The error multiplies along...  Both of these relationships are good to understand if you are really out of the ballpark for RA and pH.  To use RA and pH to make better beer you need a pH meter and the necessary salts and acids on hand to adjust your mash in process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Beer_color,_alkalinity_and_mash_pH) will probably shed some light on the subject for you (it did for me). Also, see [this article](http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Beer_color_to_mash_pH_%28v2.0%29) for a more specific discussion on the correlation of color to pH.

Remember, though, that the relationship between color and pH can be quite loose. The final remarks in the first linked article state *"the approach outlined here only provides for a crude estimation of the mash pH and that there are cases where this prediction will not be correct"*. To quote Palmer, *"You can use the calculated color of a beer recipe as a guide, but don’t rely on it as gospel to determine the appropriate amount of residual alkalinty; it is a general relationship, like cloud color and rain"*.

Hope this is helpful.

e:
Worth noting that [the experiments](http://braukaiser.com/documents/effect_of_water_and_grist_on_mash_pH.pdf) on which these conclusions are based note that *"[i]t was found that Kolbach's pH change based on residual alkalinity is generally used incorrectly in (home) brewing and that it depends on more factors than just the residual alkalinity of the brewing water when mash pH is of interest"* (the Kolbach method being cited by both the Palmer and BYO articles).

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  In the earlier days when Palmer made this color/alkalinity thing more readily known through How to Brew people took it as gospel. An easy way to avoid actually learning about and MEASURING pH at home.  Palmer got a lot of milage out of this.  As a biochemist, I think the relationship is an interesting coincidence but far from useful in most applications.  If one really wants to be concerned with pH and RA of their mash and beer then you have to have a pH meter.  Calculators and equations only take you so far, but usually not as far as the layman thinks.